# Traceback (most recent call last): ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Tags: python, dna-sequence

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhJhC.png)

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "dna.py", line 42, in 
main()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: Please provide a code snippet.  In general, you tried reading from a file after you already closed it.

Comment: https://cs50.harvard.edu/x/2020/psets/6/dna/

Answer (score 0):

`csv.reader()` operates on an open file. Please indent lines 33-37 once more.

Comment: can u elaborate please/